# Unity model faces become invisible at certain angle

Tags: unity, culling

I find certain areas of my model disappears at certain angles

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the model has several parts and the parts are separated using boolean tools in other software and thus have overlapping faces.

[image: This is not a gif]

With the help from the comment section, I was able to find the (possible) cause of the problem: the `Surface Type` of their shader is set to `Transparent`, as shown below.

[image]

The model is a photogrammetry scanned asset and then manually boolean-ed in Maya into several parts. As such, 2 parts' interfaces are essentially identical, only with a different normal direction. I assume this is tightly related to the problem.

Due to the task needing to control the opacity of individual objects, I have to set them as `Transparent`. Is there a way to fix this phenomenon while keeping the ability to control the objects' opacity?

Comment: How does the object look in the scene tree when imported into Unity? Do the sections that appear and disappear get imported as separate gameObjects, or is it all one mesh?

Comment: @Philipp They are imported separately and then assembled into a prefab

Comment: Are you using one of the standard unity shaders? Are the objects static or dynamic? Are you doing anything clever with occlusion culling? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/occlusion-culling-window.html

Comment: @Basic the occlusion settings are left by default and I did not change anything. The objects are using a shader graph though, with Blending Mode set to `Alpha`, Render Face set to `Front`, Depth Write set to `Force enabled`, and Depth Test set to `L Equal`, not sure if they have something to do with the issue.

Comment: That covers the concerns I had in mind. Purely in the interests of narrowing down the problem, can you swap to a standard shader and see if the issue persists? Then at least we can start eliminating things like issues with the mesh/scene setup.

Comment: @Basic I think you are right, I tried to use a blank shader and it displayed without a problem. The issue came back on once I switched the Surface Type of the blank shader from `Opaque` to `Transparent`. But since I need to control the opacity of the objects, I have to keep them transparent type...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Transparent objects won't write to the depth buffer, so I'd guess it's an issue with the depth buffer and culling, however, I'm not familiar enough with Unity's rendering/culling to help diagnose farther. I'd suggest a re-read of https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html and probably update your question to include the additional info about the shader.